# Keep Trello lists' customized names in place for each new board I create in an organization

Tags: trello, list, trello-organization

The only thing I still need to do is to find a way to keep the lists customized names in place for each new board I create in an organization.

Let's say I have four lists:

`One` `Two` `Three` `Four`

When I create my new board (which is weekly) I would like it to have these names for the lists instead of the default ones (to do, doing, done) so I would not have to rename them each time.

Do you have a suggestion on how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar to this.

All I did was create a new board (with all lists named correctly) aswell as labels and other thins.
Then I renamed the whole board "~template~" (where the ~ makes it appear on top of all board, at least for me at the time speaking).

Whenever I need a new board I simply copy my template board and rename it :)

Hope that helps you.